# STEPWISE duplication of the characters in a string

Tags: java, string, recursion, for-loop

I a Java beginner and would like some help writing code that duplicates every character **stepwise** in a given string using only a main method.

So for example,

Input String: Hello (but the code should work for ANY string)

Output:

HH
HHee
HHeell
HHeellll
HHeelllloo

So after each character is duplicated and added to any previous duplications, the program terminates. Does this call for multiple loops?

So far, I have the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length ; i++) {
    char c = s.charAt(i);
    System.out.println(c);

    int j = 0;
    while (j < length) {
    j = j+1;
    i++;
    s = new StringBuffer(s).insert(i, c).toString();

    System.out.println(s);
}

}
```

I am trying to nest loops since that's how I assume this is to be solved but I'm not getting anywhere close. I would appreciate any help or direction....

Comment: look at the variable that you're incrementing and the `for` loop variable.

Answer (score 1):

-you are reusing variable i. be sure to check its value on each step
-and check the use of the substring() method

Comment: So should I be using a second int variable? My code is now this:

for (int i = 0; i < length ; i++) {
 char c = s.charAt(i);
 System.out.println(c);
 
 int j = 0;
 while (j < length) {
 j = j+1;
 i++;
 s = new StringBuffer(s).insert(i, c).toString();
 
 System.out.println(s);
}

Answer (score 0):

```
public class StringHelper {
    public static String duplicate(String s, String prefix){
        if(s.equals("")) return "";
        char c=s.charAt(0);
        String ret=prefix+c+c;
        return ret+" "+duplicate(s.substring(1),ret);
    }
    public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println(duplicate("Hello",""));
    }
}
```

Direct:

```
public static void main(String []args){
        String s="Hello"; //if you need to keep the original array, save it in temp and work with temp
        String prefix="";
        while(!s.equals("")){
            char c=s.charAt(0);
            prefix+=""+c+c;
            System.out.print(prefix+" ");
            s=s.substring(1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but is there any way to do this with only a main method and not a second one? I'll try to break it down in the meantime

Comment: Thank you, but is there any way to do this with only a main method and not a second one? I'm still trying to separate it

Comment: I have added it with original answer